# Marketing Cloud Email Studio AmpScript in email template sent by trigger

Tags: salesforce, email, salesforce-marketing-cloud, ampscript

We have an email template that works perfectly fine, but as soon as I put the following ampscript in, the email just errors out:

```
%%[
Var @result,@pass_link,@account_id
Set @pass_link = wallet_pass_url
Set @account_id = AccountID
Set @result =UpdateSingleSalesforceObject('Account',@account_id,'HY_VIP_Benefits_URL__c',@pass_link)
]%%
```

All the variables are sent to the trigger endpoint and properly fill the dataextension and populate it properly, but for some reason UpdateSingleSalesForceObject is breaking the email, and it just errors out.  I have limited access to marketing cloud, so I do not believe I can dig into the errors anymore with my access level, but I see it increment the errors when I look at the trigger (it goes from in the queue to error).  Under admin it does say salesforce connection active.

Answer (score 0):

Have to exist a properly setup connection among Salesforce and SFMC.

> Updates a record in an object in your **integrated** Salesforce account

That is achieved using the [Marketing Cloud connector](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_co_marketing_cloud_connect.htm&type=5). Please refer to the official documentation to properly setup this integration.

If You don't have the proper rights to do so, please request it to the SFMC Admin.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the id being passed was from
Sandbox and caused an error as marketing cloud was connected to production.  If the id does not match apparently it errors.